A syntactic characterisation of morphisms of algebraic theories whose induced algebraic functors admit right adjoints
Let $f : S \to T$ be a morphism of algebraic theories. Such a morphism induces a monadic functor $f^* : \mathrm{Mod}(T) \to \mathrm{Mod}(S)$ (hence $f^*$ has a left adjoint). We may view $f$ syntactically as assigning to each operator in $S$ a term in $T$ with the same arity, satisfying the given equations.
Question. Is there a syntactic characterisation of those morphisms $f$ for which $f^*$ admits  a right adjoint?
By page 7 of Wraith's 1970 Algebras over theories, it is necessary that $f$ exhibits a quotient of an extension of $T$ by unary operations. In other words, the theory $T$ is given by extending the theory $S$ by new unary operations, and then imposing additional equations. The question above may therefore be reformulated to ask which equations we can/must impose on an extension of $S$ by unary operations, so that $f^*$ admits a right adjoint.
It is possible that a complete characterisation is implicit in Wraith's work, but I did not see how to extract it. Pages 71 – 72 of Wraith's lecture notes on Algebraic Theories also seems relevant, though it is not clear to me whether this provides a characterisation.

This is essentially the question which forgetful functors of algebraic structures are cocontinuous.

Not necessarily forgetful, but otherwise yes: functors between categories of models for algebraic theories automatically satisfy the solution set condition. (It is also equivalent to asking when such functors preserve finite coproducts, as they automatically preserve sifted colimits.) However, this property doesn't seem practical to check in concrete examples, which is why I am interested in a syntactic characterisation.

I thought about this a bit when trying to understand $\lambda$-rings – the same example that Wraith offers – and I think the answer is basically what is remarked in the cited lecture notes: it is necessary and sufficient for the new unary operations to distribute over the existing operations in a coherent fashion.
I state a precise theorem below.
For an algebraic theory $T$, let $U^T : \textbf{Mod} (T) \to \textbf{Set}$ be the forgetful functor and let $F_T$ be its left adjoint.
To avoid confusion, and to align with the notation, we speak of $T$-models rather than $T$-algebras or $T$-modules (which are reserved for more complicated things in Wraith's terminology; see below).
For a morphism $f : S \to T$ of algebraic theories, let $U^f : \textbf{Mod} (T) \to \textbf{Mod} (S)$ be the forgetful functor and let $F_f$ be its left adjoint; following the lecture notes, say $f$ is essential if $U^f$ has a right adjoint $H_f$.
(I am avoiding the star notation.)
Recall that coproducts in $\textbf{Mod} (S)$ can be constructed by taking the free $S$-model generated by the disjoint union of the underlying sets of the summands and the quotienting by the evident congruence generated by the "multiplication tables" of the summands; somewhat more precisely, given $S$-models $M_\alpha$ ($0 \le \alpha < \kappa$), the counit gives us a canonical effective regular epimorphism:
$$F_S \left( \sum_{0 \le \alpha < \kappa} U^S (M_\alpha) \right) \cong  \sum_{0 \le \alpha < \kappa} F_S U^S (M_\alpha) \twoheadrightarrow \sum_{0 \le \alpha < \kappa} M_\alpha$$
Of course, we may make the same argument for any ad hoc choice of generators for each $M_\alpha$ to get a smaller generating set for $\sum_\alpha M_\alpha$.
It follows that if $U^f$ preserves coproducts of free $T$-models – e.g. if $f$ is essential – then all $\kappa$-ary $T$-operations can be expressed as (the image under $f$ of) an $S$-operation applied to $\kappa$-many unary $T$-operations:
$$U^T F^T (\kappa) \cong U^T \left( \sum_\kappa F^T (1) \right) \cong U^S U^f \left( \sum_\kappa F^T (1) \right) \cong U^S \left( \sum_\kappa U^f F^T (1) \right)$$
This demonstrates $f$ is an extension of $S$ by unary operations that satisfy a distributive law over $S$-operations, at least in the informal sense that any unary $T$-operation applied to any $S$-operation can be rewritten as an $S$-operation applied to some unary $T$-operations.
Let me try to be more precise.
Recall that (for any algebraic theory $T$) $F_T (1)$ admits a canonical internal co-$T$-model structure: indeed,
$$U^T (B) \cong \textrm{Hom}_T (F_T (1), B)$$
and $U^T (B)$ obviously has a natural $T$-model structure, so $F_T (1)$ acquires a co-$T$-model structure (by general Yoneda yoga, i.e. chasing the identity).
This generalises: when $f$ is essential,
$$U^T H_f (A) \cong \textrm{Hom}_T (F_T (1), H_f (A)) \cong \textrm{Hom}_S (U^f F_T (1), A)$$
so $U^f F_T (1)$ acquires the structure of an internal co-$T$-model in $\textbf{Mod} (S)$.
(The earlier version is the special case where $S = T$ and $f = \textrm{id}_T$.)
Furthermore, since $U^f$ preserves coproducts, and both structures are transported from the same source, the structure on $U^f F_T (1)$ can be identified with (the image under $U^f$ of) the structure on $F_T (1)$.
Of course, this is also compatible with the structure on $F_S (1)$ in the sense that the adjunction unit $F_S (1) \to U^f F_T (1)$ is an internal co-$S$-homomorphism (where we are using the obvious analogue of $U^f$ to regard $U^f F_T (1)$ as an internal co-$S$-model).
We have thus proved half of the following:
Theorem.
$f$ is essential if and only if there is an internal co-$T$-model $C$ in $\textbf{Mod} (S)$ with the following properties:

(The underlying object of) $C$ is $U^f F_T (1)$.

For every $\kappa$ and every $t : F_T (1) \to F_T (\kappa)$ in $\textbf{Mod} (T)$, the morphism $U^f (t)$ factors as the given structure morphism $t_C : U^f F_T (1) \to \sum_\kappa U^f F_T (1)$ followed by the canonical morphism $\sum_\kappa U^f F_T (1) \to U^f F_T (\kappa)$ in $\textbf{Mod} (S)$.

The adjunction unit $F_S (1) \to U^f F_T (1)$ (in $\textbf{Mod} (S)$) is an internal co-$S$-homomorphism (where we are using the analogue of $U^f$ to regard $C$ as an internal co-$S$-model).


The "if" direction remains to be proven.
Assume we have such an internal co-$T$-model $C$ in $\textbf{Mod} (S)$.
By Yoneda, we see that $\sum_\kappa U^f F_T (1) \to U^f F_T (\kappa)$ is surjective, so (as discussed earlier) every $\kappa$-ary $T$-operation can be rewritten as an $S$-operation applied to $\kappa$-many unary $T$-operations; the hypotheses of the theorem are (implicitly) the coherence conditions we need to make this work properly.
Indeed, the structure on $C$ means we may define a functor $H^C : \textbf{Mod} (S) \to \textbf{Mod} (T)$ by setting:
$$H^C (A) = \textrm{Hom}_S (C, A)$$
(The RHS acquires a $T$-model structure because $\textrm{Hom}_S (-, A) : \textbf{Mod} (S)^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Set}$ preserves limits.)
We will show that $H^C$ is a right adjoint of $U^f$ by constructing a unit and counit.
The action of the functor $U^f$ gives a natural $T$-homomorphism $B \to H^C U^f (B)$, by the hypothesis on the factorisation of $U^f (t)$ for each $t : F_T (1) \to F_T (\kappa)$:
$$B \cong \textrm{Hom}_T (F_T (1), B) \to \textrm{Hom}_S (U^f F_T (1), U^f (B)) = H^C U^f (B)$$
Furthermore, we have a natural $S$-homomorphism $U^f H^C (A) \to A$, by the hypothesis on the adjunction unit $F_S (1) \to U^f F_T (1)$:
$$U^f H^C (A) = U^f \textrm{Hom}_S (U^f F_T (1), A) \to \textrm{Hom}_S (F_S (1), A) \cong A$$
These are the desired unit and counit: the triangle identities basically reduce to the fact that $F_T \cong F_f F_S$ and $U^T = U^S U^f$ as adjoints.
Thus, $f$ is indeed essential.

Note that $C$ in the theorem is (among other things) simultaneously an $S$-model and an internal co-$T$-model in $\textbf{Mod} (S)$.
Wraith calls such a thing an $(T, S)$-bimodel.
By Yoneda and the adjoint lifting theorem, the category of $(T, S)$-bimodels is equivalent to the category of left adjoint functors $L : \textbf{Mod} (T) \to \textbf{Mod} (S)$; the $(T, S)$-bimodel corresponding to $L$ is $L F_T (1)$.
In particular, we may define a tensor product of bimodels by identifying it with functor composition.
This makes the category of $(S, S)$-bimodels a (non-symmetric) monoidal category, and Wraith defines an $S$-algebra to be a monoid in this monoidal category.
This, of course, is simply a monad structure on the corresponding endofunctor on $\textbf{Mod} (S)$; a module over an $S$-algebra is simply an algebra for the corresponding monad on $\textbf{Mod} (S)$.
Since the underlying endofunctor of such a monad preserves colimits, the (crude) monadicity theorem can be applied to deduce that the the obvious forgetful functor from the category of modules to $\textbf{Set}$ is monadic, so we obtain an algebraic theory $T$ and an essential morphism $f : S \to T$.
It is also more or less immediate that, for every $T$ and every essential morphism $f : S \to T$, there is corresponding $S$-algebra such that $\textbf{Mod} (T)$ is equivalent to the category of modules over that $S$-algebra as categories over $\textbf{Mod} (S)$.
What the theorem above gives is, in a sense, halfway between these two characterisations.

Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for; I find your characterisation very clarifying.
